# How can I make Sql Server accept dd/mm/yyyy format?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

So I have an Excel file with values as 19/09/2011 on a column called "Dates". I selected the entire column in Excel - Format cells - Location: English(UK) and selected the sample value of "14/03/2011" so that the day appears before the month.

Now, using a simple import package in Visual Studio, I imported the data in Sql Server (I used 3 tasks generated by the wizard: Drop table, create table structure in Sql Server, and actual import).

In the create table task, I specified the dates column type as date.
After that, to test the outcome, I selected dates in the Sql Server table ordering it by dates desc.

So I get this, all rumble-jumbled (this is supposed to be only September data, so we should have only "09" after the year):

```
2011-12-09
2011-11-09
2011-10-09
2011-09-30
2011-09-29
2011-09-28
2011-09-27
2011-09-26
2011-09-25
2011-09-24
2011-09-23
2011-09-22
2011-09-21
2011-09-20
2011-09-19
2011-09-18
2011-09-17
2011-09-16
2011-09-15
2011-09-14
2011-09-13
2011-09-09
2011-08-09
2011-07-09
2011-06-09
2011-05-09
2011-04-09
2011-03-09
2011-02-09
2011-01-09
```

Comment: I assume a few solutions are possible: 1. setting Sql Server to UK date format (dd/mm/yyyy) but I don't know how to do that 2. maybe a convertion task in Visual Studio to specify format 3. my most preferred variant: is there a way to specify the format of the date on that column when creating the table structure for importing?

Comment: What makes you think they are all *rumble-jumbled*?, it seems in perfect order to me. They are stored correctly, the are just being displayed on that format

Comment: Lamak, forgot to specify: it's only September there! I'll add this detail in the initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get data into a datetime column you can:

```
select cast(replace(date_col, '-', '') as datetime)
```

as strings in the format of yyyymmdd such as `20120928` can always be cast to datetime regardless of the format settings (as they are a certain ISO format).

To get data out of a table in a particular format you can either `CAST` or `CONVERT` or use

```
SET DATEFORMAT
```

e.g.

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
GO

SELECT GETDATE()
```

**EDIT**: using convert would look like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103)
```

which returns:

> 28/09/2012

Comment: Thank davek but still unclear because I had tried Dateformat too and no results. Where should I place that?

Comment: set dateformat is only session-relevant, so it may not have any effect if you only set it once.

Comment: I did this `SELECT *, CONVERT(date, [Dates], 103) AS dates1 INTO TABLE1 FROM TABLE0; GO` and then for a test: `SELECT distinct day(date1) FROM TABLE1; GO` and it worked. I got 9 in resturn so test successful.

Comment: From what I know it's not possible to change a datetype when the table is populated with values so I had to create a new table, TABLE1.

Answer (score 0):

Use function `CONVERT (DATETIME, @sDateOfBirth,101)`

Here is link for the same http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Thanks Aditya. So let's clarify an issue: assuming I need to select the rows were day=09. This means the dates continue to be seen as mm/dd by Sql Server, to avoid that each time I want to apply a condition to the dates, I will need to apply the condition to the converted date in dd/mm format?

Comment: you can make function for that